# Add an image in a HTML table structure

Tags: html, css, jsp

[image]So in the login page of my application I want to add an image at the top left corner. The front-end developer in my team has already refused that it is not possible to add an image. I have tried changing the code but not able to get the image at the correct place. The jsp code is as follows:

```
   <%@page language="java" session="false"%>
<%@include file='SSOCommonHeader.jsp' %>
<jsp:include page="keypad.jsp" />
<title><%=rb.getString("SSO_LOGIN_PAGE_TITLE")%></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/login.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/ssodomain.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/SSOLogin_<%=langCode%>.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/tfaAuth.js'></script>
<%if(!SSOConfig.isAppletMode()){%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=DOJO_BASE_PATH%>/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/sso.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/ssojsutils.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ux/javascript/thirdParty/CryptoJS/3.1.2/components/core-min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ux/javascript/thirdParty/CryptoJS/3.1.2/rollups/sha1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ux/javascript/thirdParty/CryptoJS/3.1.2/rollups/sha256.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ux/javascript/thirdParty/CryptoJS/3.1.2/rollups/sha512.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ux/javascript/thirdParty/CryptoJS/3.1.2/components/enc-base64-min.js'></script>
<%}else{%>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/ssoappletutils.js'></script>
<%}%>
<script type='text/javascript' src='ui/javascripts/login.js'></script>

<iframe src="ui/dskFrame.html" height="0" width="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script>
function goToBankJsp()
{   
    parent.window.location.href = "ui/SSOHome.jsp";
}
setSSOResourceBundle(SSOJSResourceBundle);
setLoginStatus();
setGlobals(<%=SSOConfig.isAppletMode()%>, <%=SSOConfig.get(SSOConstants.SSO_DEBUG_LEVEL)%>);
SSOUtils.log(1, "SSO","onLoad","isAppletMode="+isAppletMode);
function populateUserAndSetPwdFocus()
{
    if(isAppletMode){
        var docClientApp = window.parent.appletFrame.document.ClientApp;
        if(docClientApp && docClientApp.isActive())
        {
            if ("<%=SSOConstants.YES%>" ==  docClientApp.getUserResetConfirmation())
            {
                document.loginForm.usertxt.value = docClientApp.getUserName();
                document.loginForm.usertxt.readOnly = true;
                document.loginForm.passtxt.focus();
            }
        } 
    }
    else{
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            if(!("dojo" in window)){
                var sMsg = SSOJSResourceBundle["SSO_ERR_NO_DOJO"].replace("##DOJO_BASE_PATH##", '<%=DOJO_BASE_PATH%>');
                alert(sMsg);
            }},2000);
        var userID = "";
        <%if(SSOUtils.htmlEncode((String)request.getParameter(SSOConstants.PARAM_USER_ID)) != null){%>
            userID = '<%=SSOUtils.htmlEncode((String)request.getParameter(SSOConstants.PARAM_USER_ID))%>';
        <%}%>
        if(userID != ""){
            document.loginForm.usertxt.value = userID;
            document.loginForm.usertxt.readOnly = true;
            document.loginForm.RESET_FLAG.value = '<%=SSOConstants.YES%>';
            document.loginForm.passtxt.focus();
        }
    }
}
top.document.title='<%=rb.getString("SSO_TITLE")%>';
</script>
<%  
String challenge = "";
String authType = "";
String showVKpad = null;
String requestTok = null;
String requestType = null;
String newUILinkEnabled = SSOConfig.get(SSOConstants.NEW_UI_LINK_ENABLED);
try 
{
    showVKpad = SSOUtils.getProperty(SSOConstants.PARAM_SHOW_VKPAD);
    challenge = (String)request.getAttribute(SSOConstants.PARAM_CHALLENGE_TOKEN); 
    authType = SSOConfig.get(SSOConstants.SEL_AUTH_TYPE);
    if(null != request.getAttribute("REQUEST_TOKEN"))
        requestTok = (String)request.getAttribute("REQUEST_TOKEN");
    else requestTok = "GET_DSK";
    if(null != request.getAttribute("REQ_TYPE"))
        requestType = (String)request.getAttribute("REQ_TYPE");
    else requestType = "GET_TOK";
}
catch(Exception e) {
    //Ignore
}
%>
</head>
<body onLoad="setFormFocus();populateUserAndSetPwdFocus();" >

<!-- 
<a href="./SSOServlet?CALLTYPE=GET_BANK_HOME_PAGE&LCLANG=<%=langCode%>">
   <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--finnav">
  Login with Fininfra New UI
</button>
</a>
  -->
<%
if(SSOConfig.isAppletMode()){
%>
<form method="post" action="SSODeskTopServlet" name="desktopForm">
<input type='hidden' name='SERVICE_TOKEN' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='USER_ID' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='SESSION_ID' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='LCLANG' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='IS_CHANGE_PWD_REQ' value=''>
</form>
<%}else{%>  <!-- TODO: Check if testSpan can be removed -->
<span id="testSpan" style="visibility:hidden;"><%=challenge%></span>
<%}%>
<div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table width="626" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="378" background="ui/images/loginbg.gif">       
    <tr valign="bottom" height="350" align="bottom"> 
    <td width="168" >  </td>  
      <td>
    <form method="post" action="SSOServlet" name="loginForm" autocomplete="off">     
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >             
            <tr valign="top" height="35">                           
              <td width="15%" align="left">
              <span class="loginpassword"><%=rb.getString("SSO_USER_ID")%></span>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="txtbox" id="usertxt" name="usertxt" size="15" maxlength="<%=SSOConfig.get(SSOConstants.SSO_MAX_USER_ID_LENGTH)%>" onChange="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" value="">
              </td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="top" height="35">              
                <td align="left">
        <img src="ui/images/hbc_bs_logo.png" align="top" style="height:50%;width: 50%">
                  <span class="loginpassword"><%=rb.getString("SSO_PWD")%></span>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                  <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="txtbox" id="passtxt" name="passtxt" size="17" maxlength="<%=SSOConfig.get(SSOConstants.SSO_MAX_PWD_LENGTH)%>" onKeyPress="var keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode; if(keyCode == '13') {login(document.loginForm, document.desktopForm); } ">
                <% 
                    if (SSOConstants.YES.equalsIgnoreCase(showVKpad)){
                %>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="chkKeypad"  onClick="doKeyPad(document.loginForm,'passtxt')"><span class="loginpassword"><%=rb.getString("SSO_V_KPAD_USE")%></span>
                 <%}%>
                  </td>
                  </tr>                  
                  <tr valign="center" height="35">
                  <td>
                  </td>
                  
                  
                  <!-- for Login button -->
                  <td>
                   <input type="button" class="loginbutton" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="<%=rb.getString("SSO_GO")%>" onClick="login(document.loginForm, document.desktopForm)">
                   <% 
                     if (SSOConstants.YES.equalsIgnoreCase(newUILinkEnabled)){
                   %>
                   <a href="#" onClick="goToBankJsp()" style="font-size: 13px;font-family: arial;text-decoration: none;display: block;margin-top: 10px;">Login with New UI - BETA</a>                 
                  <%}%>
                   </td>
                  </tr>
               <!-- end Login button -->        
              </td>
            </tr>               
          </table>
          <input type="hidden" name="langCode" value="<%=langCode%>">            
          <input type="hidden" name="LCLANG" value="<%=langCode%>">
          <input type="hidden" id="buffer" name="buffer" value=""/>
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.CALLTYPE%>" value="<%=SSOConstants.CALLTYPE_AUTH%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_AUTH_TYPE%>" value="<%=authType%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_REQ_TYPE%>" value="<%=requestType%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_SESSION_ID%>" value="">
          <!-- TODO : Enable below 2 for Auth and TFA scenario -->
          <input type="hidden" name="<%--SSOConstants.PARAM_IS_AUTHORIZER--%>" value="false">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_TFA_DATA%>" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_REQUEST_TOKEN%>" value="<%=requestTok%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_RESPONSE_TOKEN%>" value="">             
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_USER_ID%>" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_USER_PW%>" value="">
          <input type="hidden" name="<%=SSOConstants.PARAM_RESET_FLAG%>" value="">
          <% if(request.getAttribute("response_type")!=null){%>
          <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value='<%=SSOUtils.htmlEncode((String)request.getAttribute("client_id"))%>'>
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value='<%=SSOUtils.htmlEncode((String)request.getAttribute("redirect_uri"))%>'>
                  <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value='<%=SSOUtils.htmlEncode((String)request.getAttribute("response_type"))%>'>          
          <% } %>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        
    <td colspan="2" style="font-family:Arial; padding:0px 20px; font-size:12px" class="basetext"> 
      <%=rb.getString("SSO_COPYWRIGHT")%>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
<br>



  <span id="Layer1" style="align:center; position:absolute;left:280px; top:50px; z-index:1;">
   <div id="pp_div" >
        <form  action="" name="keyPadForm" autocomplete="off">
            <style="z-index:1;display:float;visibilty:hidden;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;width:50px;height:50px;"> 
            <div id="ScriptDiv" height="20" width="40" ></div>
        </form> 
 </div>
 </span>
</body>
</html>
```

The login.css file is as follows

```
body {  
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-right: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
    padding-left: 0px;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:.65em;
        background:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto
}

.loginpassword {  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: .8em; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000000
}
.loginbutton {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    outline: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    height: 31px;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.txtbox {
    border-style: none;
    width: 195px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px;
}
.basetext {  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: .7em; 
    color: #666666  
}
a {
    color: #0071ad;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color:#008;
    background:#CED8E1;
    text-decoration:none;
}
input.mainButton {
        font-family: Tahoma;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #C3C3C3; 
        border-top: 1px solid #787878;
        border-right: 1px solid #ADADAD;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-left: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 2px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: .7em;
        cursor: hand;
        height:19px;
        width:23px;
}

.width100percentforkeypad {
    
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.width100percentforkeypad1 {
    
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;       
}
.CellBackGroundColourForKeypad {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
input.actnbutton{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #C3C3C3; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Can someone please let me know how can I add a .png file at the top left corner of this page.

Answer (score 1):

First, I've not seen such a mess since at least 10 years! This page should be redesigned entirely.

You're not showing any style so it's hard to tell what this actually looks like. I'll take a guess and say it's designed for large screens and shows some narrow login form about the center of the viewport.

In that case, you can add your image anywhere and style it with `position: absolute` and it will stick to the upper-left corner like:

```
<img src="your_url.png" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height :150px" />
```

Or set it as background for `body` using CSS

```
body {
  background: url('your_url.png') no-repeat top left;
  background-size: 200px 150px;
}
```

***Edit*** *after seeing your complete code and acknowledging you need your image at the top of the form*

Within the form named 'loginForm', there's a table. Inside that table, add the following code:

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="100">
      <img src="your_url.png" style="max-width: 278px; max-height: 100px;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

`max-width` is set to fit the rest of the form. `max-height` you can change as needed to fit your needs. Of course replace `your_url.png` with a valid path to your actual image.

Made a snippet to test this below. It does not render exactly as your screenshot, but close to it. There must be a few missing parts to your code.

```css
body {  
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-right: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    padding-top: 0px; 
    padding-right: 0px; 
    padding-bottom: 0px; 
    padding-left: 0px;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:.65em;
        background:#ffffff;
    overflow:auto
}

.loginpassword {  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: .8em; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #000000
}
.loginbutton {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    outline: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px 16px;
    height: 31px;
    min-width: 90px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.txtbox {
    border-style: none;
    width: 195px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px;
}
.basetext {  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size: .7em; 
    color: #666666  
}
a {
    color: #0071ad;
    background: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color:#008;
    background:#CED8E1;
    text-decoration:none;
}
input.mainButton {
        font-family: Tahoma;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #C3C3C3; 
        border-top: 1px solid #787878;
        border-right: 1px solid #ADADAD;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        border-left: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        display: block;
        padding-left: 2px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: .7em;
        cursor: hand;
        height:19px;
        width:23px;
}

.width100percentforkeypad {
    
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.width100percentforkeypad1 {
    
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;       
}
.CellBackGroundColourForKeypad {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
input.actnbutton{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: #C3C3C3; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- TODO: Check if testSpan can be removed -->
  <span id="testSpan" style="visibility:hidden;">challenge not visible</span>
  <div align="center">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="626" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="378" background="ui/images/loginbg.gif">
      <tr valign="bottom" height="350" align="bottom">
        <td width="168"> </td>
        <td>
          <form method="post" action="SSOServlet" name="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="100">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" style="max-width: 278px; max-height: 100px;" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tr valign="top" height="35">
                <td width="15%" align="left">
                  <span class="loginpassword">User ID</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="txtbox" id="usertxt" name="usertxt" size="15" maxlength="100" onChange="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" value="">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="top" height="35">
                <td align="left">
                  <img src="ui/images/hbc_bs_logo.png" align="top" style="height:50%;width: 50%">
                  <span class="loginpassword">Password</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="password" autocomplete="off" class="txtbox" id="passtxt" name="passtxt" size="17" maxlength="500" onKeyPress="var keyCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode; if(keyCode == '13') {login(document.loginForm, document.desktopForm); } ">
                  <!-- keypad
                          <input type="checkbox" name="chkKeypad" onClick="doKeyPad(document.loginForm,'passtxt')"><span class="loginpassword"><%=rb.getString("SSO_V_KPAD_USE")%></span>
                          -->
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr valign="center" height="35">
                <td>
                </td>


                <!-- for Login button -->
                <td>
                  <input type="button" class="loginbutton" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="LOGIN" onClick="return false">
                  <a href="#" onClick="return false" style="font-size: 13px;font-family: arial;text-decoration: none;display: block;margin-top: 10px;">Login with New UI - BETA</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <!-- end Login button -->
            </table>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

        <td colspan="2" style="font-family:Arial; padding:0px 20px; font-size:12px" class="basetext">
          Copyright blablabla
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
  <br>



  <span id="Layer1" style="align:center; position:absolute;left:280px; top:50px; z-index:1;">
   <div id="pp_div">
        <form action="" name="keyPadForm" autocomplete="off" style="z-index:1;display:float;visibilty:hidden;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;width:50px;height:50px;"> 
            <div id="ScriptDiv" height="20" width="40"></div>
        </form> 
    </div>
 </span>
</body>
```

Comment: I have added the page screenshot for reference. The black parts are some logs or company information which i have hidden. On adding the img tag the image is coming to the bottom left, the green part is the image which I have added

Comment: Try and place the image directly in `<body>`, and add to its `style` attribute `top: 0; bottom: auto;`

Comment: after doing that, the img is displayed on the top left of the complete page and not on the top left of the login form.

Comment: Well I gave you a simple solution based on the information you shared. Without styling code, I had to make some assumptions and went for the safest course. And look at me, sending you a third message about this... you said "in the login page of my application I want to add an image at the top left corner". You got what you asked for. If you want something else, then send the full code of your page and be accurate

Comment: Added the complete code and the css code also

Comment: Done. Last time I'm doing some free work for anyone

Comment: Not exactly the place where I was looking to put the image, but thanks a lot.